# How would I load a Canvas from another scene in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, find, load, scene

What I'm trying to do inside this script in Unity is to load a different scene, and find the canvas from that scene and enable it. I already know how to enable the canvas from the same scene but the issue is how can i find and enabled a canvas from another scene.

I tried SceneManager.LoadScene(scenename); to change scene so what should I add or modify? Can someone help me?

Comment: There're two solutions:
1) Using MonoBehavior's `DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject)` for your canvas you need to be on the next scene;
2) saving somewhere your current scene's gameobjecs(canvas) and loading it again and recreate on the next scene as serialization etc;
3) same as #2, but save required data in local variables.

Comment: @KamikyIT This should rather be an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Save the canvas you want to switch to as a 'prefab' in your assets folder.

If you are loading a new scene without carrying over data from the last scene then just set up the canvas in that scene using the editor.

If you are carrying data over, or perhaps a player gameobject, then you can instantiate the canvas prefab you need. This would create it in the new scene and you can have a reference to it from wherever you chose to instatiate the prefab.

Alternatively you can have multiple canvases on the same gameobject and switch them on or off as you need them. Very useful for menus.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There're many solutions:

1. Using MonoBehavior's `DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject)` for your canvas you need to be on the next scene; You can find a lot examples in Google. Here's the link : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html
2. Saving somewhere your current scene's gameobjects(canvas) and loading it again and recreate on the next scene as serialization etc;
3. Same as #2, but save required data in local variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I understand your question.

You either want to copy a game object with all it's parameters as defined in the editor into another scene.
The best way to do that is obviously to use prefabs. [(where to start?)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html)

If you want to copy a game object and all its parameters after they have been modified at runtime, then you could use [`DontDestroyOnLoad()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) but that would mean the source scene has to be loaded at least once before the destination scene.